# how to keep fixed div on its original place?

Tags: fixed

I use this code :

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('div#left').css({ 
            "position" : 'fixed',"top" : 70 });
    } else {
        $('div#left').css({ "position" : 'relative', "top" : 0 });
    }
});
```

The `div#left` is on left side of the site (not the screen) but inside a container `div`.
My problem is that the `div#left` go to the left edge of the screen.
How can I keep it on the same place without jumping to to the far left?